# Linq lambda foreach

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Trying for wrap each string in array but it doesn't works, means foreach loop, please explain why

```
string s = "keepsakes,table runners,outdoor accessories";
List<string> keys = s.Split(',').ToList();
keys.ForEach(x => x = String.Concat("%", x, "%"));
s = String.Join(",", keys);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

need to get `"%keepsakes%,%table runners%,%outdoor accessories%"`

**UPD:**
Thanks a lot for suggestions(it's a same way)

**but** some one can answer why this is works and not works under:

object

```
    public class MyItems
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
    }
```

and func

```
        string s = "keepsakes,table runners,outdoor accessories";
        List<MyItems> keys = s.Split(',').ToList().Select(x => new MyItems(){ Item = x }).ToList();
        keys.ForEach(x => x.Item = String.Concat("%", x.Item, "%"));
        s = String.Join(",", keys.Select(x => x.Item).ToList());
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: "it doesn't works" - what happens exactly? What is the actual output? Also, what do you mean by "array"?

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach could be using `Regex` instead of LINQ:

```
string s = "keepsakes,table runners,outdoor accessories";
string pattern = "\\,+";
string replacement = "%,";

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = string.Format("%{0}%", rgx.Replace(s, replacement));
```

Edit:

The reason why it works using a class to assign the string it is because when you use the foreach in your first instance:

```
keys.ForEach(x => x = String.Concat("%", x, "%"));
```

x, elements of keys, which is a string, is a reference passed by value to the function ForEach. Take this as an example:

```
var myString = "I'm a string";

Console.WriteLine(myString);

ChangeValue(myString);

Console.WriteLine(myString);

void ChangeValue(string s)
{
    s = "something else";
}
```

If you run that snippet you'll see that `myString` won't be changed inside the method ChangeValue because we are trying to replace the reference. The same thing happens for the method `ForEach`, this is the main reason you cannot change the value of your list within the `ForEach`.

Instead if you do:

```
class MyClass{
    public string aString;
 }

void ChangeValue(MyClass s)
{
    s.aString = "something else";
}

 var myClass = new MyClass();
 myClass.aString =  "I'm a string";

 Console.WriteLine(myClass.aString);

 ChangeValue(myClass);

 Console.WriteLine(myClass.aString);
```

You acknowledge that in the second `Console.WriteLine` the value of the field aString will be changed to "something else". [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx) is a good explanation of how reference types are passed by value

Comment: Please, if you can - look at UPDated answer

Answer (score 10):

You are  not modifying the list within the `ForEach`, you are just creating strings that are assigned to the local variable `x` but then thrown away. You could use a `for`-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
{
    keys[i] = String.Concat("%", keys[i], "%");
}
```

For what it's worth, here the shorter LINQ version which also circumvents the core issue:

```
s = string.Join(",", s.Split(',').Select(str => "%" + str + "%"));
```

Comment: the only answer with explaination!

Comment: Please, if you can - look at UPDated answer

Comment: Apart from that, the second code snippet works, so i don't understand _"can somebody answer why this works and **not works** under ..."_

Comment: If you instead don't understand why it _works_ with your class' property. The reason is that the class `MyItems` is a refernce type and that you are modifying the property of each reference in `List.ForEach`. On that way you modify the original objects in the list which works as opposed to your first approach where you're trying to replace the reference itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Join` and `Select` and `Format`

```
string s = "keepsakes,table runners,outdoor accessories";

var output = string.Join(",", s.Split(',').Select(x => string.Format("%{0}%", x)));
```

Comment: Please, if you can - look at UPDated answer

Comment: @DaveBish: your update is incorrect. The second snippet works as opposed to the first and i guess OP wonders why. The reason is not related to the immutability of strings but that he changes a property of a reference type instead of trying to replace the whole reference in `List.ForEach`.

Answer (score 3):

you can do easier: replace each comma with `%,%`

```
string s = "keepsakes,table runners,outdoor accessories";
string s2 = "%" + s.Replace("," , "%,%") + "%";
```

Comment: Please, if you can - look at UPDated answer

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach (without lambdas):

```
string result = string.Concat("%", s, "%").Replace(",", "%,%");
```

Comment: Please, if you can - look at UPDated answer

Answer (score 1):

`List<>.ForEach` cannot be used to change the contents of the list.  You can either create a new list or use a `for` loop.

```
keys = keys.Select(x => "%" + x + "%").ToList();
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
{
    keys[i] = "%" + keys[i] + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the lambda passed to `List.ForEach` does not return a value.

LINQ is lazy, but `String.Join` will force enumeration:

```
var res = String.Join(",", input.Split(',').Select(s => "%" + s + "%"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The ForEach doesn't change your list of string, it will only perform an action using each string. Instead you can do it this way :

```
string s = "keepsakes,table runners,outdoor accessories";
List<string> keys = s.Split(',').Select(x => String.Concat("%", x, "%")).ToList();
s = String.Join(",", keys);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Please, if you can - look at UPDated answer